# Can scripts imported be run even if the contents of page do not load on Application launch through JMeter?

Tags: jmeter

When I launch my application through JMeter in a browser - contents of the Login page are not displayed.
So I recorded a very basic scenario - just launching the Login page of my application through fiddler and imported it as a jmx file to JMeter. When I run the script, I see that the script fails.

If JMeter is not able to launch the page while recording, will JMeter to able to run a script that is recorded from Blazemeter/Fiddler for the same page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per [JMeter project main page](https://jmeter.apache.org/):

> JMeter is not a browser, it works at protocol level. As far as web-services and remote services are concerned, JMeter looks like a browser (or rather, multiple browsers); however JMeter does not perform all the actions supported by browsers. **In particular, JMeter does not execute the Javascript found in HTML pages. Nor does it render the HTML pages as a browser does** (it's possible to view the response as HTML etc., but the timings are not included in any samples, and only one sample in one thread is ever displayed at a time).

So JMeter will **download** the [DOM](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document_Object_Model/Introduction) and the scripts (as well as images, fonts, styles, sounds, etc.) given you "tell" JMeter to do this via [HTTP Request Defaults](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/why-its-so-important-use-jmeters-http-request-defaults)

[image]

however it **won't execute the JavaScript**.

If your scripts don't generate any network requests - you can just skip it as scripts are executed in browser context so you should not be too interested in the timings. If the scripts are triggering network requests - you should be able to record them using JMeter's [HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_proxy_step_by_step.html) and add them after the "main" request which gets the content of your login page.

You can put the "main" and the "scripts" request(s) under the [Transaction Controller](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Transaction_Controller) - this way you will also get "cumulative" time of their execution.